# Fetching mysql values with alternative index values

Tags: mysql

I have simplified the values from mysql and given. In this master_course_id values should come alternatively like required output

**Database values**

```
master_course_id    register_number

        1               A1
        1               A2
        1               A3
        2               B1
        2               B2
        2               B3
        3               C1
        3               C2
        3               C3
        4               D1
        4               D2
        4               D3
        5               E1
        5               E2
        5               E3
```

**Current Output**

```
master_course_id register_number

        1            A1
        2            B1
        3            C1
        4            D1
        5            E1
        1            A2
        2            B2
        3            C2
        4            D2
        5            E2
        1            A3
        2            B3
        3            C3
        4            D3
        5            E3
```

**Required Output**

```
master_course_id register_number

        1             A1
        2             B1
        1             A2
        2             B2
        1             A3
        2             B3
        3             C1
        4             D1
        3             C2
        4             D2
        3             C3
        4             D3
        5             E1
        5             E2
        5             E3
```

**Mysql Query**

```
SELECT register_number
FROM (

        SELECT master_course_id, register_number, 
            @position := IF(master_course_id = @prev_course, @position+1, 1) AS position, 
            @prev_course := master_course_id
        FROM (SELECT * FROM master 
              WHERE master_course_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
              ORDER BY master_course_id, register_number) AS m,
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @position := 0, @prev_course := null) AS vars
    ) AS t
    ORDER BY position, master_course_id
```

course_id 1 and 2 should alternatively come first if either one id finished means it should move to the next id 3 or 4 likewise till end it should loop. Which means course_id comes alternatively how to acheive this in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL you would use `row_number() over (partition by master_course_id order by register_number)` to get a position for a `register_number` within a `master_course_id` group. More clumsily you can achieve the same with a subquery as shown in my query below.

The rest is an `order by` clause matching your needs.

```
select master_course_id, register_number
from
(
  select
    master_course_id,
    register_number,
    (
      select count(*)
      from master before
      where before.master_course_id = master.master_course_id
      and before.register_number < master.register_number
    ) as pos_in_course
  from master
) data
order by
  (master_course_id - 1) DIV 2, -- first id (1|2), then id (3|4), then id (5|6), ...
  pos_in_course, -- first id (1|2) pos 1, then id (1|2) pos 2, ...
  master_course_id -- first id 1 pos 1, then id 2 pos 1, then id 1 pos 2, ...
```

You can do the same with MySQL variables as you are already trying. I cannot check this, but I suppose your query already does this correctly and you only need to apply the appropriate order by clause.

And here at last is the same query in standard SQL:

```
select master_course_id, register_number
from master
order by 
  floor((master_course_id - 1) / 2),
  row_number() over (partition by master_course_id order by register_number),
  master_course_id;
```

Comment: have taken idea from this